# zsh parse error after alias do=…

Tags: zsh, alias

I have the following `.zshrc` file in my home directory:

```
# modify the prompt to contain git branch name if applicable
git_prompt_info() {
  current_branch=$(git current-branch 2> /dev/null)
  if [[ -n $current_branch ]]; then
    echo " %{$fg_bold[green]%}$current_branch%{$reset_color%}"
  fi
}
setopt promptsubst
export PS1='${SSH_CONNECTION+"%{$fg_bold[green]%}%n@%m:"}%{$fg_bold[blue]%}%c%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info) %# '

# load our own completion functions
fpath=(~/.zsh/completion $fpath)

# completion
autoload -U compinit
compinit

# load custom executable functions
for function in ~/.zsh/functions/*; do
  source $function
done

# makes color constants available
autoload -U colors
colors

# enable colored output from ls, etc
export CLICOLOR=1

# history settings
setopt hist_ignore_all_dups inc_append_history
HISTFILE=~/.zhistory
HISTSIZE=4096
SAVEHIST=4096

# awesome cd movements from zshkit
setopt autocd autopushd pushdminus pushdsilent pushdtohome cdablevars
DIRSTACKSIZE=5

# Enable extended globbing
setopt extendedglob

# Allow [ or ] whereever you want
unsetopt nomatch

# vi mode
bindkey -v
bindkey "^F" vi-cmd-mode
bindkey jj vi-cmd-mode

# handy keybindings
bindkey "^A" beginning-of-line
bindkey "^E" end-of-line
bindkey "^R" history-incremental-search-backward
bindkey "^P" history-search-backward
bindkey "^Y" accept-and-hold
bindkey "^N" insert-last-word
bindkey -s "^T" "^[Isudo ^[A" # "t" for "toughguy"

# aliases
[[ -f ~/.aliases ]] && source ~/.aliases

# extra files in ~/.zsh/configs/pre , ~/.zsh/configs , and ~/.zsh/configs/post
# these are loaded first, second, and third, respectively.
_load_settings() {
  _dir="$1"
  if [ -d "$_dir" ]; then
    if [ -d "$_dir/pre" ]; then
      for config in "$_dir"/pre/**/*(N-.); do
        . $config
      done
    fi

    for config in "$_dir"/**/*(N-.); do
      case "$config" in
        "$_dir"/pre/*)
          :
          ;;
        "$_dir"/post/*)
          :
          ;;
        *)
          if [ -f $config ]; then
            . $config
          fi
          ;;
      esac
    done

    if [ -d "$_dir/post" ]; then
      for config in "$_dir"/post/**/*(N-.); do
        . $config
      done
    fi
  fi
}
_load_settings "$HOME/.zsh/configs"

# Local config
[[ -f ~/.zshrc.local ]] && source ~/.zshrc.local
```

Unfortunately, when I start my terminal, I get the following error:

```
/home/steven/.zshrc:72: parse error near `fi'
```

The problem seems to be in my aliases files. I have two aliases files:
1. `.aliases`
2. `.aliases.local`

`.aliases` is loaded, and within that there is the following command to load `.aliases.local`:

```
[[ -f ~/.aliases.local ]] && source ~/.aliases.local
```

Within my `.aliases.local` file I have the two following aliases:

```
alias server='ssh -p xxx user@xx.xx.xxx.xxx'
alias do='ssh -L xxxx:127.0.0.1:xxxx -N -f -l user -p xxxx xx.xx.xxx.xxx'
```

These are basically aliases to ssh into my server (the first alias), and also to establish a secure tunnel so I can use a VNC client to the server.

These two aliases are working correctly, but when I define them in `.aliases.local`, I keep getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing obvious here. Do you get the same error if there aren't any included files? In particular `.aliases` could be setting up a bad alias.

Comment: You are right - it must be my aliases file. When I move my `.aliases` file so that it doesn't load, I don't get the error.

Comment: I've updated the original question to reflect this information @Gilles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`do` is a reserved word in the shell. It's part of the syntax of `while` and `for` loops. When you define it as an alias, the alias takes precedence over the reserved word. So the shell sees, after alias expansion:

```
if [ -d "$_dir/pre" ]; then
  for config in "$_dir"/pre/**/*(N-.); ssh -L xxxx:127.0.0.1:xxxx -N -f -l user -p xxxx xx.xx.xxx.xxx
    . $config
  done
fi
```

I don't know why zsh is complaining about the `fi` and not about the `done` or the lack of `do` after the semicolon, but anyhow, this isn't valid syntax.

You need to pick a different name for your alias. Avoid all [reserved words](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Reserved-Words).

Comment: @Gilles; Note that `do` is **no** *reserved word* in bourne like shells; it's perfectly valid to write, e.g., `for do in do doo dooo ; do print echo $do ; done`. You just can't have it at places where a command is expected.

Comment: @Janis “Reserved word” is what most shell manuals, including ksh and POSIX and (most relevantly for this answer) zsh use. The Bourne manual doesn't give a name. They are indeed only reserved at the beginning of a command (and a few other contexts), but they are called “reserved words” nonetheless.

Comment: @Gilles; the ksh documentation, e.g., felt the need to explicitly clarify that they are "reserved" only in "specific contexts", because the term "reserved word" is generally not defined that way but it has an absolute meaning about whether it may or may not be used by users. I think in the broad context of Stack Exchange questions that should be made clear. I propose to not use the term "Reserved Word" unconditionally, but only if it's truely reserved (as usually programming languages use the term), or to explicitly note the restriction (as the ksh docs do).